# Copy Blobs from one storage account to another storage account using Python

Tags: python, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying the following code to copy all blobs from one storage account into another, in the same resource group:

```
src_storage_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(src_storage['connectionString'])
src_container = src_storage_client.get_container_client(src_storage['containerName'])

dst_storage_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(dst_storage['connectionString'])
dst_container = dst_storage_client.get_container_client(dst_storage['containerName'])

try:
    for blob in src_container.list_blobs():            
        src_blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(src_storage['connectionString'], src_storage['containerName'], blob.name)
        new_blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(dst_storage['connectionString'], dst_storage['containerName'], blob.name)
        new_blob.start_copy_from_url(src_blob.url)
```

I receive the following error:

> azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: Operation returned an
> invalid status 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Please
> refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.'

I tried *generate_blob_sas* and *generate_account_sas* to no use!
I checked out other examples, documentations, and repos but none matched my case, unless I missed something.

Using that same new_blob instance with upload method, it works perfectly. However, I want to copy rather than download-then-upload-again.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your issue is correct. And you could use `container.get_blob_client(blobName)` instead in the loop.

```
for blob in src_container.list_blobs():            
    src_blob = src_container.get_blob_client(blob.name)
    new_blob = dst_container.get_blob_client(blob.name)
    new_blob.start_copy_from_url(src_blob.url)
```

It's important to check if `src_blob.url` or `blob.name` contain the special characters or space, they need to be encode first. It seems caused by special blobs, please try with a blob. When you use SAS token, you should check the allowed permissions and expired time.